# unnest sql with postgres return empty strings

Tags: postgresql

I have this query on postgresql

```
SELECT 
    unnest(array[ sale_contact_name, purchase_contact_name, admin_contact_name]) AS name , 
    unnest(array[ sale_contact_mobile  , purchase_contact_mobile , admin_contact_mobile ]) AS mobile  ,
    unnest(array[ sale_contact_phone, purchase_contact_phone, admin_contact_phone]) AS phone
from company_t
where  companyCode = 'anything'   ;
```

I get empty string if there is no data. 
I don't wnat to get these empty string ,how can I do that

Comment: Not related to the Q but: `select * from company_t, unnest(array[...], array[...],...) where ...` could be more convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CASE` statements to handle the empty strings should they occur:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.name = ''   THEN 'Alt name'   ELSE t.name END,
       CASE WHEN t.mobile = '' THEN 'Alt mobile' ELSE t.mobile END,
       CASE WHEN t.phone = ''  THEN 'Alt phone'  ELSE t.phone END
FROM
(
    SELECT unnest(array[ sale_contact_name, purchase_contact_name, admin_contact_name]) AS name,
           unnest(array[ sale_contact_mobile, purchase_contact_mobile , admin_contact_mobile ]) AS mobile,
           unnest(array[ sale_contact_phone, purchase_contact_phone, admin_contact_phone]) AS phone
    FROM company_t
    WHERE companyCode = 'anything'
) t
```